# Qt: How to catch Ctrl + A key press on macOS

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to implement default Emacs shortcuts supported by macOS.
Example of the code:

```
void InputField::keyPressEventInner(QKeyEvent *e) {
if(e->modifiers().testFlag(Qt::MetaModifier) && e->key() == Qt::Key_A) {
   // Does not work
}
```

I've tried to use `QGuiApplication::keyboardModifiers()`:

```
if(QGuiApplication::keyboardModifiers().testFlag(Qt::MetaModifier) && e->key() == Qt::Key_A) {
// does not work
}
```

`QKeyEvent::nativeModifiers()` always returns `0` when a modifier key is pressed.

Note: I use `MetaModifier` because according to the [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#KeyboardModifier-enum):

> On macOS, the ControlModifier value corresponds to the Command keys on the keyboard, and the MetaModifier value corresponds to the Control keys.

How do I catch the Control key?

Qt 5.12.8
XCode 11.7

Update:
I can catch either `Ctrl` or `a`:

```
if(e->modifiers() & Qt::MetaModifier))
```

or

```
if(e->key() == Qt::Key_A)
```

Comment: As a sanity check, did you at least try to use Qt::ControlModifier?

Comment: I see your keyPressEventInner() routine. Are you explicitly overriding keyPressEvent and keyReleaseEvent?

Comment: @JarMan, yes, `ControlModifier` catches the Command button press.

Comment: @mzimmers, only `keyPressEvent` is overridden:
```
 void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *e) override {
  return outer()->keyPressEventInner(e);
 }
```